# Running script-block command with param using Start-Process

Tags: powershell

Why does powershell think `$dir` is `null` when setting the location but not when writing the output?

```
$command = {
    param($dir)
    Set-Location $dir
    Write-Output $dir
}

# run the command as administrator
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command $command 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'"
```

This results in the following output:

```
Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument
"path" to a non-null value.
At line:3 char:2
+  Set-Location $dir
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

---

I also tried:

```
$command = {
    param($dir)
    Set-Location $dir
    Write-Output $dir
}

$outerCommand = {
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $command -ArgumentList 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'
}

# run the command as administrator
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command $outerCommand"
```

But then I got:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScriptBlock'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for
the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:2 char:30
+  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $command 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'
+                              ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

---

Possible clue: if I set a local variable instead of using a param, it works perfectly:

```
$command = {
    $dir = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'
    Set-Location $dir
    Write-Output $dir
}

# run the command as administrator
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command $command"
```

---

Similar Q/As that didn't quite answer my question:

- [PowerShell - Start-Process and Cmdline Switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches) (I'm not trying to run an exe with command line switches, I'm trying to run powershell with a script block that needs a param passed into it)
- [How to use powershell.exe with -Command using a scriptblock and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342632/how-to-use-powershell-exe-with-command-using-a-scriptblock-and-parameters) (doesn't use `Start-Process`, which I need to run as administrator)
- [Powershell Value of argument path is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923735/powershell-value-of-argument-path-is-null) (uses `Invoke-Command` rather than `Start-Process`)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are passing $command into it specifically and not just specifying the location in an argument variable like so `$arguments = "-NoExit Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $arguments`

Comment: @OwainEsau, This is a stripped down example. My real script is too large and complex to be easily put into a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`$command` is a *script block* (`{ ... }`) and *stringifying* a script block results in its *literal* contents**, excluding the enclosing `{` and `}`.

Therefore, your expandable string `"-NoExit -Command $command 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'"` literally expands to the following string - note the missing `{ ... }` around the original script block:

```bash
 -NoExit -Command 
    param($dir)
    Set-Location $dir
    Write-Output $dir
 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'
```

Due to the loss of the enclosing `{` and `}`, the new `powershell` process spawned by `Start-Process` quietly ignored the orphaned `param($dir)` statement and, given that the new process therefore had no `$dir` variable  (given that it isn't an *automatic* variable either), the command failed, because `Set-Location $dir` was tantamount to `Set-Location $null`, which fails.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note that **you can never pass script blocks *as such* to `Start-Process` - all arguments must be *strings***, because only strings can be passed to *external processes*.

---

The simplest solution in your case is to:

- **enclose the `$command` reference in your expandable string in `{ ... }`** to compensate for the loss of this enclosure due to stringification
- and **prepend `&`** to ensure *invocation* of the resulting script block in the new process.

Here's a working solution:

```bash
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList `
  "-NoExit -Command & { $command } 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'"
```

**Important:**

- While not needed with the specific `-Command` argument at hand, because of how the PowerShell CLI parses its process command line when `-Command` is used, **embedded `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"`**,<sup>[2]</sup> as shown in the following example:

```bash
# Script block with embedded " chars.
$command = {
    param($dir)
    Set-Location $dir
    "Current dir: $dir"
}

# Embed the script block with " escaped as \"
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList `
  "-NoExit -Command & { $($command -replace '"', '\"') } 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'"
```

---

<sup>[1] It fails in *Windows PowerShell*; in PowerShell *Core*, it is tantamount to `Set-Location` *without arguments*, which changes to the current user's home folder.</sup>

<sup>[2] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for details.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but I wanted to place all of the commands needed for `Start-Process -ArgumentList` into a variable.  Thanks to [`mklement0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54994550/11653053)'s answer above, I managed to find the solution.

Here's a slightly alternative answer, which includes [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)'s `-Command` (and any other parameters), in a `Here-String` [[link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692792(v=technet.10))] [[link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1#here-strings)]:

```
$commandString = @'
    -NoExit -Command & {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green \"Hello, new window!\"
        Set-Location -Path \"c:\\\"
        Get-ChildItem
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    }
'@

Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList $commandString
```