# Cannot run powershell command via command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, smtp, command-prompt, adsi

I'm attempting to check the RelayForAuth setting for my Windows SMTP Server using the below commands. Powershell appears to display the correct result 'False' but when running the same command via command prompt, it generates an error:

Powershell Example:

```
([ADSI]"IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1".RelayForAuth -like "*0*")
```

Output:

```
False
```

Command Prompt Example:

```
powershell -command "([ADSI]"IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1".RelayForAuth -like "*0*")"
```

Output:

```
At line:1 char:8
+ ([ADSI]IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1.RelayForAuth -like *0*)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1.RelayForAuth' in expression or 
statement.
At line:1 char:8
+ ([ADSI]IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1.RelayForAuth -like *0*)
+        ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:56
+ ([ADSI]IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1.RelayForAuth -like *0*)
+                                                        ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Now change the inner double quotes to single.  Also, you could put the working line in a powershell script and run it with `powershell script.ps1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you're *nesting* (embedding) `"` chars.** - to be passed *verbatim* to PowerShell - inside the *syntactic* outer double-quoting (`"..."`), **you must *escape*** those nested `"` chars.

Even though PowerShell-*internally* `` ` `` serves as the escape character, **calling the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe` / `pwsh`) *from the outside* (`cmd.exe`) requires `\`-escaping of `"`**:

```sh
# Embedded " chars. must be \-escaped
powershell -command "([ADSI]\"IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1\").RelayForAuth -like \"*0*\""
```

Note that **you can avoid the need for this escaping if you *single*-quote the strings inside the overall `"..."` string**.
While this works fine in your case, given that your strings have only *verbatim* content, note that this is **generally only an option if no [*string interpolation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) is required**:

```sh
# Embedded strings use '...' -> no escaping needed.
powershell -command "([ADSI]'IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1').RelayForAuth -like '*0*'"
```

*Caveat*: **Using single-quoting to enclose the overall command (`'...'`) does *not* work as expected from `cmd.exe`**: the latter doesn't recognize these as quoting, and PowerShell simply interprets the string as using *its* syntax for a verbatim string, and therefore simply *prints* the contents of the string.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375).