# How can I execute this line of code in the run box?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, quoting

I have the following line of code that I use to download and combine dns text records from my website and execute them in powershell. I can run this command just fine from the console but can not figure out how to effectively run it from the run box (win+r)

```
1..3|%{$p+=Resolve-DnsName "$_.website.com." -Ty TXT -EA 0|% S*s};& ([scriptblock]::Create($p))
```

Below is a simplified version I use to pull down and execute a single dns text record using a single word instead of iterating through through numbers and combining them.

```
powershell . (nslookup -q=txt example.website.com)[-1]
```

The above simplified version works fine from the console but in order for it to work in the run box it has to be modified as seen below:

```
powershell "powershell . (nslookup -q=txt sub.website.com)[-1]"
```

I can not seem to find a way to modify that first example in a way that allows me to execute it from the run box. Doing something like the example below errors out. I have tried about 20 variations of the code below with no success

```
powershell .(1..3|%{$p+=Resolve-DnsName "$_.website.com." -Ty TXT -EA 0|% S*s};& ([scriptblock]::Create($p)))
```

Comment: You may need a continuation character : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-line-continuation-in-powershell/

Comment: What is `S*s` doing? What is the error?

Comment: @jdweng, the line break in the original form of the question was a posting artifact (since corrected). In fact, the Run dialog won't even let you submit a multi-line command.

Comment: @jfrmilner, `S*s` selects a property name by wildcard pattern, which only works if only _one_ property of the input object matches. Looks like this was done for brevity. Try `'foo' | % L*h`, which is the same as `'foo' | % Length`

Comment: @mklement0 : I use the back tick all the time in my powershell scripts.

Comment: @jdweng, so do I. How does this relate to my comment and to the question at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
powershell 1..3|%{$p+=Resolve-DnsName \"$_.website.com.\" -Ty TXT -EA 0|% S*s};& ([scriptblock]::Create($p)))
```

- The crucial change is to escape the `"` chars. as `\"`, so that PowerShell considers them part of the command to execute.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for more information.
- There's no reason to use `. (...)` for execution - just use `...` directly, as shown.

Note that the above command only works from *no-shell* environments such as the Windows Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>) - to execute it from `cmd.exe`, you'd need additional quoting or escaping.