# Failed to process input: The parameter must begin with a / or -

Tags: docker, powershell, iis

I am running a Dockerfile but every time it stops at one point.

```
RUN powershell %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='Test',path='Test.cgi',verb='*',modules="IsapiModule",scriptProcessor="c:\Test.dll",resourceType="Unspecified", preCondition="bitness64"]"


Failed to process input: The parameter 'verb=*' must begin with a / or -
```

I am struggling for hours. What could be the reason?

Comment: Looks like you need to escape all double-quotes in parameters that follow `verb='*'`. Not familiar with appcmd, but you can try replacing these quotes by single-quotes (like `modules='IsapiModule'`), escape them with a backslash (like `modules=\"IsapiModule\"`), or perhaps even by doubling (like `modules=""IsapiModule""`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're trying to invoke `appcmd.exe` *via PowerShell* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)), even though the `appcmd.exe` command line doesn't require the features of that shell - it seems to be composed of literal strings only.
- Your use of `%windir%` implies that your Dockerfile uses the *default* shell on Windows, namely `cmd.exe`

Therefore, you should be able to formulate your `appcmd.exe` command line as you would submit it from a `cmd.exe` session:

```
RUN %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='Test',path='Test.cgi',verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='c:\Test.dll',resourceType='Unspecified',preCondition='bitness64']
```

Note:

- All quoting in the remainder of the argument that starts with `/+` now uses only `'...'`, for consistency; since no argument-internal `"` chars. are therefore in play, the need to *escape* them goes away.
- No spaces are allowed in the remainder of the argument.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- When you use the `-Command` / `-c` PowerShell CLI parameter (which is *implied* in the absence of `-File`), `"` characters to be passed through *as part of the PowerShell command* must be *escaped* as `\"`.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for an explanation.
- Since your `/+` argument also contains *embedded* `"` chars., as part of the argument, you would have to escape them *twice*, namely as `` `\" `` (sic)