# How to use iwr to download files to a directory with a space in it from runbox?

Tags: powershell

First off I know the obvious answer is to not use a directory with a space in it, but at this point it is just bothering me that I do not know how to.

```
$f = "$env:userprofile/desktop/art folder/art.png"

iwr DropBoxUrl -o $f
```

this works fine in a powershell console
but from the runbox it shows the following error:

```
At line:1 char:22
+ $s = $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\art folder\art.png; iwr https://www.dropb ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\desktop\art' in expression or statement.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Windows Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>):

- Its use requires calling the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)
- Since you're trying to execute *commands* (rather than a *script file* (`.ps1`)), use of the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter is required.

  - Note: While `-Command` (`-c`) can be omitted with `powershell.exe`, because it is the default, you *must* use it with `pwsh`, whose default is `-File`
- Any `"` characters that are to become part of the PowerShell command(s) to execute *must be escaped* as `\"`.

  - If you don't escape them, they are *removed* during the initial command-line parsing, resulting in the error you saw.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for an explanation.

Therefore, using `powershell.exe`:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -c "$f = \"$env:userprofile/desktop/art folder/art.png\"; iwr DropBoxUrl -o $f"
```

Note: I've added the `-noexit` switch so as to keep the session open, which allows you to see the results.