# How to run sudo command via ssh by powershell in cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, cmd

```
echo kali | ssh -t kali:kali@192.168.158.129  'sudo -S bash -c ""echo 123 >> /etc/123"" '
```

This command only work in powershell, but not work in cmd.exe.

Failed command in cmd.exe like this:

```
powershell -command "echo kali | ssh -t kali:kali@192.168.158.129  'sudo -S bash -c ""echo 123 >> /etc/123"" '"
# permission denied: /etc/123
```

Comment: Try replacing ```""echo 123 >> /etc/123""``` with ```\"\"echo 123 >> /etc/123\"\"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) has provided the crucial pointer:

When calling **PowerShell's CLI**, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), *from the outside*:

- **escape as `\"`** those `"` chars. that you want to be retained as part of the PowerShell command to execute - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for more information.

In short: **replace `""` with `\"\"`**:

```
powershell -command "echo kali | ssh -t kali:kali@192.168.158.129  'sudo -S bash -c \"\"echo 123 >> /etc/123\"\" '"
```

---

Note that **the quoting you're using from *inside* PowerShell, 
`'sudo -S bash -c ""echo 123 >> /etc/123"" '`, 
only works due to a long-standing bug with respect to passing arguments with embedded `"` to *external programs*, such as `ssh`**:

- PowerShell places verbatim `"sudo -S bash -c ""echo 123 >> /etc/123"" "` on the process command line constructed behind the scenes, i.e. it *neglects to escape* the embedded `"` in the overall `"..."` string, which results in `ssh` parsing the argument as verbatim `sudo -S bash -c "echo 123 >> /etc/123"`  (as desired), because it understands `""` inside `"..."` as a single, escaped `"` - while many CLIs on Windows do, the most widely supported escape syntax is `\"`.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.

**In PowerShell (Core) 7.3.0 and above, if `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard'` is in effect, simply using `"` as-is inside your `'...'` string is enough:

`'sudo -S bash -c "echo 123 >> /etc/123" '`**,

 which then causes PowerShell to *automatically* escape the `"` as `\"`, placing the following verbatim on the behind-the-scenes process command line:
`"sudo -S bash -c \"echo 123 >> /etc/123\" "`

However, if you were to use the latter *from `cmd.exe`*, you'd run afoul of the *latter*'s parsing: because `cmd.exe` doesn't understand  `\"` as an *escaped* `"`, it sees the `>>` as being *outside* a `"..."` string and therefore interpret its *itself*, *up front*.

In such a corner case, you tan cake advantage of the fact that [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core)* CLI, alternatively understands `""` as escaped `"` chars. insider overall `"..."`:

```
# PowerShell (Core) only: alternatively use "" to escape " on the command line.
# !! "" is enough if $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard' is in effect 
# !! in your case, which by default is only true
# !! for PowerShell 7.3.0 and at least up to 7.3.1, and may change again.
# !! Otherwise, use """" (2 escaped ") in your case.
pwsh -command "echo kali | ssh -t kali:kali@192.168.158.129  'sudo -S bash -c ""echo 123 >> /etc/123"" '"
```

With the *Windows PowerShell* CLI (`powershell.exe`), you'd have to use `"^""` (sic) instead of `""` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).