# How to add a quotation mark in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, cygwin, quotes

#### I wanted to make a command to install the **Scoop** package manager for **Windows**

It should be run from the **cygwin** shell
It works like this:

1. Requests administrator permission
2. Opens a **PowerShell** window
3. Runs the **Scoop** installation command

---

###### I made this command, it looks like this:

```bash
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command iex ""& {$(irm get.scoop.sh)} -RunAsAdmin""" -Verb RunAs -Wait'
```

This command runs, but there is one problem - **there is no quotation mark** next to the "&" symbol

[**Error photo**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtHPI.png)

#### Error text:

```
At line:1 char:5
+ iex & {# Issue Tracker: https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install/iss ...
+     ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quot
ation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:339 char:30
+         set args=%args:(=``(%,
+                              ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:689 char:31
+ $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
+                               ~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
At line:241 char:30
+         if ($retries -eq 10) {
+                              ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:240 char:29
+     while ($retries -le 10) {
+                             ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:108 char:33
+ function Test-ValidateParameter {
+                                 ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:1 char:7
+ iex & {# Issue Tracker: https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install/iss ...
+       ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

---

As you can see, the script is loaded and enclosed in curly braces, but still **not executed** because there is no quotation mark next to the "&" character

And now it is interpreted as follows:

```
iex & {<scoop installation script>} -RunAsAdmin
```

And it should be like this:

```
iex "& {<scoop installation script>} -RunAsAdmin"
```

I took the script itself from the official **Scoop** installation documentation - https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install#for-admin

So please help me put quotes in my install command

---

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**:

- Note the Cygwin context, which means that the syntax rules of POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` initially apply; notably this means:

  - The embedded `"` are *automatically* escaped as `\"` for the *outer* `powershell.exe` process command line.
  - When the outer `powershell.exe` process then makes the *inner* `powershell.exe` call, it constructs a raw Windows process command line, where *manual* `\`-escaping of embedded `"` chars. is necessary.

---

**Solution**:

- Escape the embedded `""` as `\""`:

  - `""` (as used by you) escapes the `"` for inclusion inside the enclosing `"..."` string in the outer `powershell.exe` call
  - `\` then escapes the resulting `"` for use with the inner `powershell.exe -Command` CLI call.

    - With `-Command`, the PowerShell CLI *removes* unescaped `"` instances during command-line parsing, before interpreting the resulting code as PowerShell code; this is the initial problem you ran into - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for details.
  - Note: `` \`" `` is an alternative to `\""`, given that `"` inside `"..."` can also be escaped as `` `" ``
- `` ` ``-escape the `$` in `$(irm get.scoop.sh)`

  - Because the outer `powershell.exe` call uses `"..."` quoting around its `-ArgumentList` value, the `$` inside it must be `` ` ``-escaped in order to prevent *premature* expansion (interpolation), given that the intent is for the *inner* - then-elevated - `powershell.exe` call to  interpret the `$(...)` subexpression.

```bash
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command iex \""& {`$(irm get.scoop.sh)} -RunAsAdmin\""" -Verb RunAs -Wait'
```