# Powershell on Windows 10 - Start an elevated process and pass parameters to it

Tags: powershell

From a (non-elevated) shell I want to start an elevated powershell process and pass a command line parameter to it.

Here's my sample code in test.ps1:

```
# Define a mandatory parameter
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$PRM_NAME = "myParameter"
) 

$Env:PRM1=$PRM_NAME

# Start a new PowerShell process with elevated privileges
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @(
    {
        Write-Host "Parameter Name = " $Env:PRM1
        sleep 3;
    }
) -Verb RunAs
```

I call this script with

```
.\test.ps1 test
```

The elevated shell starts alright, but does not know $Env:PRM1. This is because the elevated process does not inherit the environment from the parent process.

The modified script:

```
# Define a mandatory parameter
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$PRM_NAME = "myParameter"
) 

$Env:PRM1=$PRM_NAME

# Start a new PowerShell process with elevated privileges
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @(
    {
        Write-Host "Parameter Name = " $Env:PRM1
        sleep 3;
    }
) -Verb RunAs -Environment @{"PRM1"=$Env:PRM1}
```

gives an error message:

```
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Environment'.
```

I searched stackoverflow for similar problems/solutions and found one suggestion that works.

[How can I elevate Powershell while keeping the current working directory AND maintain all parameters passed to the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774566/how-can-i-elevate-powershell-while-keeping-the-current-working-directory-and-mai)

However, this seems very complex to me. Is there a simpler way or does it really have to be this complex to pass on a parameter to an elevated process?

Comment: Are you just trying to relaunch a script (with arguments) in an elevated session? or are you trying to execute arbitrary code with arguments in an elevated session?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994071/running-script-block-command-with-param-using-start-process - related?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: In case my question hasn't given it away, I'm not really a powershell expert. The problem I'm trying to solve is a workaround for a problem with my USB<->Ethernet adapter. After my laptop wakes up from sleep the adapter is not working properly. I haven't found a permanent fix, but a workaround is unplugging and plugging the adapter back in. A more elegant workaround is to disable/re-enable the adapter, which requires admin privileges. Some of my colleagues have the same problem, that's why I wanted a script that takes the name of the NIC as an argument.

Comment: @n0rd: Thanks for the link. It's useful, but I don't think I would have made the connection immediately. My powershell skills are not sufficient for that.

Comment: This isn't really answering your question the "good" way, but I wanted to mention winsudo, I used to use it because it installed easily with scoop at work but now scoop is reported as malicious by our IT. This runs any command with elevation by popping up that prompt asking if you want to allow. Works with both cmd.exe and powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By security-minded design, an elevated process launched from a non-elevated one does *not* inherit the latter's environment by default.
- While [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) does have an `-Environment` parameter in PowerShell (Core) v7.4+, the latter is - unfortunately - *quietly ignored* in combination with `-Verb RunAs` (the argument that requests elevation) as of v7.4.0.

  - At least at the level of the underlying .NET APIs, attempting to modify the environment for an elevated process is *actively prevented*.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - See [GitHub issue #20923](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20923) for a discussion.

Therefore, you must pass any values as what are *conceptually* arguments, but **requires use of *string interpolation*** to "bake" these values into the PowerShell code being invoked:

```bash
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList @"
  -Command 
  Write-Host \"Parameter Name = \" '$PRM_NAME'
  sleep 3
"@
```

- Note the use of an [expandable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings), i.e an *interpolating* string that *up front* embeds the *value* of the caller's `$PRM_NAME` variable into the string.

  - `$PRM_NAME` is enclosed in `'...'`, so as to ensure that its value is preserved as a *single* value / argument (i.e. it is passed as a [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) so as to prevent potential renewed interpolation); if there's a chance that the value of `$PRM_NAME` itself contains `'` characters, use `'$($PRM_NAME -replace "'", "''"))'` instead.
  - Note that you generally cannot pass a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) *as such* to `Start-Process`, because the latter only accepts *string(s)* as `-ArgumentList` argument(s); if you do, the script block is *stringified*, i.e its *verbatim content* (sans `{` and `}`) is passed as a string.
  - **Note**:

    - In order to declare (parameter) *variables* to use *as part of the code to execute in the elevated process*, `` ` ``-escape their `$` sigil, as shown below, in order to prevent up-front expansion.
    - Because of how the PowerShell CLI parses its process command line when `-Command` is used, **embedded `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for details.
- The `-Command` parameter isn't strictly necessary when using [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, where it is the default, but would be for [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+), which now defaults to `-File`.
- It probably isn't worth doing, because it doesn't gain you much, but you can use *argument-passing as part of the `-Command` argument*, which still relies on passing the *interpolated* value, however:

  ```bash
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList @"
    -NoProfile -Command & {
      param(`$prm)
      Write-Host \"Parameter Name = \" `$prm
      sleep 3
    } '$PRM_NAME'
  "@
  ```

  - Note how the `$` in the `$prm` parameter declaration and later reference must be `` ` ``-escaped so as to prevent up-front expansion.

---

<sup>[1] In the sample code below, due to `UseShellExecute = $true` - which is the prerequisite for being able to use `Verb = 'RunAs'`, i.e. with elevation - attempts to modify the list of environment variables via `.Environment` (or `.EnvironmentVariables` are actively prevented with the following exception: `The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables.`

Sample code (if you set `UseShellExecute` to `$false`, i.e. run *non-elevated*, the environment modification succeeds):

`$psi = [Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{ Verb = 'RunAs'; FileName = 'cmd'; Arguments = '/c echo [%foo%] & pause'; UseShellExecute = $true }; $psi.Environment.Add('foo', 'hi!'); [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi).WaitForExit()`</sup>

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. This works perfectly.
It's a bit unfortunate that the documentation from MS is not more clear about the fact that ```-Environment``` and ```-Verb RunAs``` are mutually exclusive.
It's a bit like Inception wrt all the escaping required. What level are we on :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @bambino350. I've added a link to a GitHub issue to the answer that request that an _error_ occur when this combination is attempted (because I _think_ that combining these parameters meaningfully isn't possible by security-minded design).

Comment: This is going a bit beyond the original question now, but I'm interested to understand why you think that allowing the combination of the two arguments is not safe, when you just showed me a way to circumnavigate the restriction by using a here-string?

Comment: @bambino350, that's a fair question - the security argument applies to not inheriting the caller's environment _by default_, but at least at the level of the underlying .NET APIs you are actively _prevented_ from passing an explicitly modified environment when you request elevation - see the footnote I've just added to the answer.